# Where are SQL Server user credentials stored?

Tags: sql-server

Where are SQL Server user name and password stored?

Comment: Not clear elaborate more

Answer (score 8):

In the DB called "master", you can view them with:

```
SELECT * FROM master.sys.syslogins
```

However passwords are encrypted.

As per Richard's comment: please note that syslogins is no longer a physical table (in SQL server 2005 and 2008) but only a view provided for backwards compatibility.

Comment: It is not "stored" in syslogins. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178593.aspx syslogins is a VIEW only, especially since you use `sys.`.

Comment: @Richard: you're right, I should have said that "they are stored in master, **you can see them with**...

Comment: I would have asked "how do I view" instead of "where are.. stored" which implied (to me) a question seeking another answer than this one

Comment: @Richard if the OP updates the question to include the version we can be more specific. With what I know so far, that's the only query that's guaranteed to work (and could even be the actual physical table in case of SQL 2000)

Comment: I did stress the point about your use of `sys.` - all objects in the sys namespace are views. If you were referring to `master.dbo.syslogins` then you have a better case.